# is it possible to namespace a whole rails app (ie adding to the url path)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, router

I have a rails app that has approx 30 matches in routes.rb

```
match '/send-email' => 'index#send_email'
match '/forgot-password' => 'users#forgot_password', :as => :forgot_password
match '/forgot-password-confirmation' => 'users#forgot_password_confirmation'
match '/user/save-password' => 'users#save_password', :as => 'edit_users_password'
match '/user/home', :to => 'users#home'
match '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => "user_show"
```

What would be the best way to add a prepending route?

```
like /user/home -> /app/user/home,
    /user/show/:id -> /app/user/show/:id
```

Is there a way to just apply this globally? And then put in an exception for root? and a single route for pretty urls like domain.com/user-name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [namespace](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).

```
namespace :app do
  match '/send-email' => 'index#send_email'
  match '/forgot-password' => 'users#forgot_password', :as => :forgot_password
  match '/forgot-password-confirmation' => 'users#forgot_password_confirmation'
  match '/user/save-password' => 'users#save_password', :as => 'edit_users_password'
  match '/user/home', :to => 'users#home'
  match '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => "user_show"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use scope in your routes
It will work without name prefix as if you use namespace 
example

```
scope "/app" do
 match '/send-email' => 'index#send_email'
  match '/forgot-password' => 'users#forgot_password', :as => :forgot_password
  match '/forgot-password-confirmation' => 'users#forgot_password_confirmation'
  match '/user/save-password' => 'users#save_password', :as => 'edit_users_password'
  match '/user/home', :to => 'users#home'
  match '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => "user_show"

end
```